Basis for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}, \sqrt{d}]$ where $e,d$ are different squarefree integers greater than 1.
$\textbf{Moral:}$ Trying to compute the discriminant of this ring.
I claim that a basis for this ring is $\{1, \sqrt{d}, \sqrt{e}, \sqrt{ed}\}$ but I've been told by a peer that this may not be the case. However, I don't see anything wrong with my proof below:
First, note that $\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$ is basis
for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}][\sqrt{e}]$ over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}]$: $\sqrt{d}$ is integral over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}]$
since it is a root of the monic polynomial $m(x) = x^2 - d \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}][x]$ and hence $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}][\sqrt{e}]$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}]$ with basis
$\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$ $(\dagger)$ (linear independence follows since if $e$ and $d$ are squarefree, so is $ed$). Similarly, $\sqrt{e}$ is integral over $\mathbb Z$ since it is a root of $m(x) = x^2 - e \in \mathbb Z[x]$. Hence $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}]$ is a finitely generated
$\mathbb Z$-module with basis $\{1,\sqrt{e}\}$ $(\ast)$. Now, let $c_1,\dots,c_4 \in \mathbb Z$ and suppose that $c_1 + c_2\sqrt{e} + c_3\sqrt{d} + c_4\sqrt{e}\sqrt{d} = 0$. If we
consider this linear combination as a linear combination of the basis $\{1,\sqrt{d}\}$ for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}][\sqrt{e}]$
over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}]$ then we have that
\begin{equation}
  1\cdot \left[ c_1 + c_2\sqrt{e} \right] + \left[ c_3 + c_4\sqrt{e} \right]\sqrt{d} = 0
  \label{eq:1}
 \end{equation}
By $(\dagger)$ the equation above implies that $c_1 + c_2\sqrt{e} = 0$ and that $c_3 + c_4\sqrt{e} = 0$. But then by $(\ast)$ we have
that $c_1 = \dots = c_4 =0 $. It is clear that $\operatorname{Span} \mathcal A \subseteq \mathbb Z[\sqrt{d},\sqrt{e}]$. Now let $\alpha \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{e},\sqrt{d}]$. By $(\dagger)$ we have that $\alpha = \beta_1 + \beta_2\sqrt{d}$ for some $\beta_1,\beta_2
 \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{e}]$. By $(\ast)$ we have that $\beta_1 = r_1 + r_2\sqrt{e}$ and $\beta_2 = r_3 + r_4\sqrt{e}$ for some $r_i \in \mathbb Z$. Substituting $\beta_1$ and
$\beta_2$ into our equation for $\alpha$ implies that $\alpha \in \operatorname{Span} \mathcal{A}$, as desired. QED

Your peer may be thinking about the ring of integers for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{e},\sqrt{d})$ instead. This, if I remember my Marcus exercise correctly, is not always given by what you wrote

Well, what if $e=d$?

@FShrike Right so the goal is that we are trying to compute the discriminant of this ring. But why would that not be a basis?

@lulu sorry forgot to add that they are different.

See this post, for example, with $d=2,e=3$ and the problem with $\frac{1}{2}$. The ring has an integral basis ${1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}}$

The question has nothing to do with the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{e}, \sqrt{d})$, its just asking to compute the discriminant of the given ring.

By  this Lemma, $,1,\sqrt d,\sqrt e,\sqrt{de},$ are $\Bbb Q$-linearly independent $\iff  \sqrt d,\sqrt e,\sqrt{de}$ are all irrational. $\ \ $

"Has nothing to do with the ring" yet you need to compute something about this ring. To start with, your friend is correct that the ring is not always writable in this way, so thinking about (a basis for) this ring is genuinely helpful!!

@FShrike But that's where I'm stuck. I don't see anything wrong with the bases I gave above.

@A.Z But you’re writing a basis for a different ring! Maybe. Apologies if I’m misremembering but I think this ring of integers is not $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{e},\sqrt{d}]$ in general. So you’re writing the correct basis for the incorrect ring, I think

To stress:  I think the OP has been quite clear in asserting that the ring in question is not intended to be the ring of integers in the associated number field.   To be sure, the "peer" might have been thinking about the ring of integers.  But for the given ring, the indicated basis is correct.  In particular $\frac {\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3}2$ can't be written as $a\sqrt 2 +b\sqrt 3 +c\sqrt 6$ for integers $a,b,c$ even though it happens to be an algebraic integer in that number field (easy exercise).

Yes just to emphasize I’m trying to compute the discriminant of the indicated ring. The question did not mention anything about the ring of integers
